# How to solve this Gradle Error in Intellij Idea

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

First time in Intellij IDEA Community, and I can't continue because of this error:
`Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:`
I just downloaded the source code of this repo: https://github.com/FabricMC/fabric-example-mod
And when I do "open project", It doesn't want to build.
I re-downloaded Intellij Community but no success...

Comment: Can you please paste the entire output?

Comment: Paste the entire error you get. Also specify IDE version you use and the JDK with is set in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Gradle JVM**.